# Can I round the corners of ID2D1Bitmap or IWICBitmapSource?

Tags: winapi, graphics, direct2d

I have a square picture with which I would like to round the edges. I did it with System Bitmap and GraphicsPath, but it's different here.
[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjLX1.png)

[What i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT7QF.png)

[Spell normal rect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBinL.png)

[What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0elP.png)

[Spell round corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgDO7.png)

Maybe I'm thinking wrong and it's as simple as possible. I tried Googling, but I didn't find anything accurate. I've seen different ways through mask and effect, but I'm not sure. Can someone suggest I will be very grateful, I have just started my journey.

The code I use to crop the corners of an image in c#.

```
public static Image RoundCorners(string fileName, int cornerRadius)
{
    var image = CreateImageFromGame(fileName); //Получаем растр

    if (image is not null)
    {
        cornerRadius *= 2;
        Bitmap roundedImage = new(image.Width, image.Height);
        GraphicsPath gp = new();
        gp.AddArc(0, 0, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 180, 90);
        gp.AddArc(0 + roundedImage.Width - cornerRadius, 0, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 270, 90);
        gp.AddArc(0 + roundedImage.Width - cornerRadius, 0 + roundedImage.Height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 0, 90);
        gp.AddArc(0, 0 + roundedImage.Height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, 90, 90);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(roundedImage))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.SetClip(gp);
            gr.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        }

        return roundedImage;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Specific actions I should try or code

Comment: You have to use an ID2D1Effect with a shader.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Could you advise me where I could look at this in more detail and more clearly? In order to understand better what you mean by "ID2D1Effect with a shader"

Comment: it's not easy. You have to use ID2D1DeviceContext as a render target which has the ability to create effects. Then you have to create a custom effect (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/custom-effects) passing a shader that does that. You need to learn more on HLSL and such.

Comment: Not sure you mean exactly by "round the edges", are you after the vignette effect? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/vignette-effect or post the input and desired output images

Comment: Whether you want to draw the outline of the specified rounded rectangle? If so, I suggest you could try to use [ID2D1RenderTarget::DrawRoundedRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-drawroundedrectangle(constd2d1_rounded_rect__id2d1brush_float_id2d1strokestyle))

Comment: @SimonMourier I added an example that I use to crop corners in c#. Is something like this possible on D2D1?

Comment: Can you put a *picture* of what you expect, input vs output

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes i added pictures. As you can see corners was rounded

Comment: @SimonMourier Maybe I need to make the pixels at the corners of the picture transparent to achieve the effect of a rounded picture? If so, could you help, how could I do this in D2D1?

Comment: It should be doable, do you have an ID2D1Bitmap or an IWicBitmapSource as input? What language?

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I get it directly from the game and can convert to these formats. I code on c# using WinAPI dll, but it's not a problem to transfer something from c++ to c#. At the moment I get a System Bitmap and execute the code that I wrote above "RoundCorners". Can I do so on D2D1Bitmap or IWicBitmapSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the [DrawRoundedRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-drawroundedrectangle(constd2d1_rounded_rect_id2d1brush_float_id2d1strokestyle)) and [FillRoundedRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-fillroundedrectangle(constd2d1_rounded_rect__id2d1brush)) methods to outline and fill a rounded rectangle.

You could try to use ID2D1Bitmap to Create a Bitmap Brush. And then you could  use the Bitmap Brush to fill a rounded rectangle.

You could refer to the Docs:

[How to Create a Bitmap Brush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-create-a-bitmap-brush)